# Unable to find an accessible element with the role "generic"

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I have want to test this component:

```
const Tag = ({
  value,
  color,
}: TagProps): ReactElement => (
  <CellContentStyled role="generic" aria-label={value as string} color={color}>
    {value as string}
  </CellContentStyled>
);
```

And this is my test :

```
test('is rendered', () => {
    render(<Tag value="99" color="red" />);
    const tag = screen.getByRole('generic', { name: '99' });
    expect(tag).toBeVisible();
  });
```

But this test fails for some reason, here is the console log:

```
Unable to find an accessible element with the role "generic" and name "99"

    There are no accessible roles. But there might be some inaccessible roles. If you wish to access them, then set the `hidden` option to `true`. Learn more about this here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole

    Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <body>
      <div>
        <span
          aria-label="99"
          class="sc-bdvvtL dVKtID"
          color="red"
          role="generic"
        >
          99
        </span>
      </div>
    </body>

       5 |   test('is rendered', () => {
       6 |     render(<Tag value="99" color="red" />);
    >  7 |     const tag = screen.getByRole('generic', { name: '99' });
         |                           ^
       8 |     expect(tag).toBeVisible();
       9 |   });
```

if I use `getByLabelText` instead of `getByRole` my test works:

```
test('is rendered', () => {
    render(<Tag value="99" color="red" />);
    const circle = screen.getByLabelText('99');
    expect(circle).toBeVisible();
  });
```

Why my test fails even though I have defined the role `generic` ?

Comment: Are you fowarding `role` to the specific element inside `CellContentStyled` component?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto yes to a `span`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check that and looks like it isn't work because `testing-library` is unable to find an element using the `generic` role with `name` option.

And that´s because `generic` its not a valid `role`, although `testing-library` is capable to finds elements with the role `generic`  only when you not use `name` options.

If you change it to e.g. `definition` it wil work:

```js
<CellContentStyled role="definition" aria-label={value as string} color={color}>
  {value as string}
</CellContentStyled>

const tag = screen.getByRole('definition', { name: '99' });
```

You just need to find the proper role for your case.

As testing-library [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#priority) says, you can check the possible roles [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques#roles) or [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions).

*A tip - if you just want to check if the element is in the document you can use `.toBeInTheDocument()` instead `toBeVisible()`. Check out the difference between each other [here](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobeinthedocument).